# IBM Worklight 6.0 - iOS app always stuck on the second launch

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst

I have an issue with Worklight 6.0 while testing my app in an iOS device and iOS Simulator.

- First, when I install the app on iOS device / iOS Simulator using Xcode "run" button, it works.
- But after I stop it and launch it again from the Springboard, it freezes / is blocked on splash screen.

I am using Eclipse 4.2.1 for Mac with Worklight 6.0 plugin. I also use Xcode 4.6.

I have tested with three newly created projects, and also with a blank one, and I always have the same issue.

When I test with a project created by a previous Worklight version, it works (for example athe HelloWorklightApp sample project).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. What's the difference between "newly created projects" and "a blank one"?
2. Did you change the HTML filename of the application in `your-project\apps\your-app\common` prior to deployment?
3. Also, while this is probably not related, but do note that if using Worklight 6.0, make sure that you have installed it in Eclipse **4.2.2**; not 4.0 not 4.1 not 4.2.1, only **4.2.2**.
4. Is this an upgraded installation of Worklight, or a new one in a new Eclipse instance and a new workspace?

Comment: #1- newly created, I mean created these days, with code inside. blanc one, I mean without adding any line of code, or changing any parameter.     #2- I haven't changed it, at least in the blanc project.    #3- I donwloaded my eclipse version from the link http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/junosr2 recommanded in Worklight plugin page. You can see what Eclipse version I got at this screenshot : https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/31521022/wl/debug/myEclipse.png

    #4- it is a new Eclipse and new Worklight installation and a new workspace

Comment: What do you mean "at least in the blank project"? so you DID change the HTML filename in the other projects? Changing the HTML filename or the mainFile value in application-descriptor.xml WILL cause the phenomena you are reporting; This is, BTW, fixed internally.

Comment: This is right, I tested again the blanc project and it works.